# Pytorch math calculation ( only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

What does it mean by only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars in this case and how do I suppose to debug it?

```
x1 = (max-min)*torch.rand(1, 21) + min
x2 = (max-min)*torch.rand(1, 21) + min
zipped_list = zip(x1, x2)
y = [math.sin(2*x1+2) * math.cos(0.5*x2)+0.5 for (x1, x2) in zipped_list]
```

output

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is because of using `math.cos` and `math.sin`. math.cos isn't vectorized, but np.cos is. use `np.sin` and `np.cos` or `torch.sin`and `torch.cos`.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because your torch tensors (x1 and x2) are not a single element tensor.

```py
t = torch.tensor([10, 20])
print(t.item()) # This will throw an error since the tensor has more than 1 element
```

```py
t = torch.tensor([10])
t.item() # This will print 10
```

To fix your issue, replace `math.sin` and `math.cos` calls with `torch.sin` and `torch.cos`. The `torch.sin` or `torch.cos` computes the sine or  cosine value on all the elements.