# only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars error with pca.fit_transform

Tags: pytorch, pca

I am trying to perform dimensionality reduction using PCA, where `outputs` is a list of tensors where each tensor has a shape of (1, 3, 32,32). Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(10)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(output)
```

But I keep getting this error, regardless of whatever I tried:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I know that the tensors with size(1,3, 32,32) is making the issue, since its looking for 1 element as the error puts it, but do not know how to solve it.
**I have tried flattening each tensor** with looping over output (don't know if its the right way of solving this issue), using the following code but it leads to error in pca:

```
new_outputs = []     
for i in outputs:
            for j in i:
                j = j.cpu()
                j = j.detach().numpy()
                j = j.flatten()
                new_outputs.append(j)

pca_result = pca.fit_transform(new_output)
```

I would appreciate if anybody can help with this error whether the flattening approach I took, is correct.

PS:I have read the existing posts ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946025/pytorch-math-calculation-only-one-element-tensors-can-be-converted-to-python-s),[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074153/cannot-convert-list-to-array-valueerror-only-one-element-tensors-can-be-conver)) discussing this error but none of them could solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Tensors are stored in a matrix with shape like `(10, 3, 32, 32)` where 10 corresponds to number of Tensors, you should flatten each like that:

```py
import torch
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
data= torch.rand((10, 3, 32, 32))
pca = PCA(10)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(data.flatten(start_dim=1))
```

`data.flatten(start_dim=1)` makes your data to be in shape `(10, 3*32*32)`

The error you posted is actually related to one of the post you linked. The PCA estimator expects array-like object with `fit()` method and you provided a list of Tensors.